# Why doesn't argparse work and send invalid option error message even if i wrote correctly?

Tags: python, pycharm, argparse

There is invalid option string error when i use argparse correctly (example file from python education website).

I tried changed the path of input and output file and symbols like \ -> / or \ in the path

the original code was

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--input", required=True,
    help="path to input image")
ap.add_argument("-o", "--output", required=True,
    help="path to output image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

and i changed argument --input and --output -> path of input and output files.

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "C:\input_01.png", required=True,
    help="path to input image")
ap.add_argument("-o", "C:\output_011.png", required=True,
    help="path to output image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

and i got this error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/command-line-arguments/shape_counter.py", line 13, in 
<module>
    help="path to input image")
  File "C:\Users\huryo\Anaconda3\lib\argparse.py", line 1339, in add_argument
    kwargs = self._get_optional_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\huryo\Anaconda3\lib\argparse.py", line 1470, in _get_optional_kwargs
    raise ValueError(msg % args)
ValueError: invalid option string 'C:\\input_01.png': must start with a character '-'
```

Comment: How did you call your python script? It looks like you need to add either -i or -o before `C:\\input_01.png`. e.g. `python shape_counter.py -i C:\input_01.png -o C:\outpunt_011.png`

Comment: The `--input` and `--output` strings in the original code were long forms of the arguments.  I have no idea what you hoped to accomplish by replacing them with filenames.

Comment: i changed the code because i got an another error message . error: the following arguments are required: -i/--input, -o/--output     so i tried to give the exact filename so that it works at least.

Comment: You got that error because you did not provide any values in the command line.  That was raised while parsing.  The new error occurs when constructing the parser, before actually parsing.  `add_argument` is not the place to set values (except possibly defaults).

Comment: Use `required=True` rarely, if ever, for an option. If a value is required, consider making it an argument, not an option.

Comment: So you are using `Pycharm`?  Then you need to learn how to provide command line values when using that!   This is really a pycharm problem, not an `argparse` one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second positional argument for `arg_parse.addargument()` is the long version of the name you want to use to refer to a variable by, so `-i` would be `--input`, you need to use the `default=...` argument if you want it to have a default value. You should change your code back to:

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--input", required=True,
    help="path to input image")
ap.add_argument("-o", "--output", required=True,
    help="path to output image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

or, if you want a default for the `-i` and `-o` you can use the argparser's default argument:

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--input", default="C:\input_01.png",
    help="path to input image")
ap.add_argument("-o", "--output", default="C:\output_011.png",
    help="path to output image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

and then call it from the command line with the command line arguments:

`python shape_counter.py -i C:\input_01.png -o C:\output_011.png`

Comment: I tried to run with original code but there was another Problem: error: the following arguments are required: -i/--input, -o/--output

Comment: @YouHur, the original code did specify that those values are `required`, didn't it?  By the way, do you know how to provide values on the command line?

Comment: @YouHur Are you running this from the command line? Calling it from a different script? did you run it the way I said to in my post (by including the -i and -o arguments)? Please post how you the command you are running in your terminal.

Comment: @MasonCaiby i try to run this in Pycharm. it works in CMD if i give the command:)

Comment: No i got still error messsage in pycharm :( that was the problem.

Comment: But you're calling it the same way in Pycharm as your CMD? Are you getting the same error, that `-i is required` or a different one? Is your Pycharm environment the same as your Command Line Environment?

Comment: *Any* positional argument to `add_argument` is considered an argument name. The only thing special about the ordering is that the first long option is used to construct a default destination name, and in the absence of any long options, the first short option is used. (Also: if a name does not start with an option character, there can be only one positional argument. If any name starts with an option character, they all must.)

Comment: @MasonCaiby so i wrote # load the input image from disk
image = cv2.imread(args["input"]) on the next line from above code. and last line is # write the output image to disk
cv2.imwrite(args["output"], image) so i expected it works like i write the command on cmd.

Comment: When you say it worked on the CMD... do you mean you fired up python in the CMD then typed the code in and it worked? Or that you called your script from the CMD and it worked? When you say you're using PyCharm, are you just trying to run it from the terminal in Pycharm? or do something else?

Comment: @MasonCaiby i solved this problem . i had to add script parameters in configuration! Thank you for your reply i appreciate it.